# Unable to locate web element in dropdown box?

Tags: java, selenium

I am unable to locate particular element in dropdown box. How do I locate the gender type "male" or "female"?

Code:

```
Reporter.log("=====Browser Session Started=====", true);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Java Selenium\\Selenium jar\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.delta.com");
    Reporter.log("=====Application Started=====", true);

    //Click SIGN UP to enter Personnel information for creating Delta login//

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("SIGN UP")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);

    //Enter Personnel information for creating Delta login//
    //To select the Prefix using drop down via ID locator 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#basicInfoTitle-button")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Select the option from drop down
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ui-id-28")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#basicInfoFirstName")).sendKeys("Suresh");
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#basicInfoMiddleName")).sendKeys("Ram");
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#basicInfoLastName")).sendKeys("Ponrajan");
    Thread.sleep(500);

    //To select the Gender using drop down via ID locator 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#basicInfoGender-button")).click();
    //Select the option from drop down  
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-40']")));
    action.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a "Select" locator.

```
Select theDropdown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#basicInfoGender-button"));

theDropdown.selectByVisibleText("Male");
```

OR

```
theDropdown.selectByVisibleText("Female");
```

you can also select it by index.

```
theDropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use send keys on dropdowns to choose which option you want.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#basicInfoGender-button")).sendKeys("male");
```